# How to customize look/feel of React Native ListView's RefreshControl

Tags: react-native

React Native's ListView has a built-in pull-to-refresh control called [RefreshControl](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol.html).  It's super easy to use.

I'd like to customize the look and feel of the control to use a different visual design, such as using a material design progress indicator.

How can I customize the look of the RefreshControl in React Native?

Comment: I made a component that allows you to use any Lottie animation as the header, not sure if that's what you're looking for, but you can check it out here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@groftware/lottie-flatlist

Answer (score 20):

You can outsmart it by doing:

- setting `transparent` properties to ListView
- Adding component with `absolute` position

Example:

```js
<View style={{height:Dimensions.get('window').height}}>
  {/* custom refresh control */}
  <View
    style={{position:'absolute',
      width:Dimensions.get('window').width, height:60,
      alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
    <Progress.CircleSnail
      color={['red', 'green', 'blue']}
      duration={700} />
  </View>
  {/* list view*/}
  <ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    refreshControl={
      <RefreshControl
        onLayout={e => console.log(e.nativeEvent)}
        // all properties must be transparent
        tintColor="transparent"
        colors={['transparent']}
        style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
        onRefresh={() => {
          this.setState({refreshing:true});
          setTimeout(() => {
            this._addRows()
          }, 2000);
        }}
      />
    }
    renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>} />
</View>
```

This is the result:

[image: sample result]

Comment: I just applied this solution and it works great. After much research, I didn't find a better solution than this one.

Comment: This solution works perfect for ios, but doesn't seem to work on Android. Both default indicator and custom indicator shows up.

Comment: you might create your own using scrollview from gesture handler with reanimated

Comment: like in this video william created a complete custom scrollview with reanimated https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZ73JdhjFC8

Answer (score 0):

You can totally do this. It requires some work though.
You can start by writing something like this.

```
<View style={styles.scrollview}>
  <View style={styles.topBar}><Text style={styles.navText}>PTR Animation</Text></View>
  <View style={styles.fillParent}>
    <Text>Customer indicator goes here...</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.fillParent}>
    <ListView
      style={{flex: 1}}
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={(rowData) => <View style={styles.row}><Text style={styles.text}>{rowData}</Text></View>}
      ref='PTRListView'
    />
  </View>
</View>
```

When you'll pull to refresh, you should see the text "Custom indicator goes here..."

Following this pattern, you can place your component instead of just a view and a text.

For the credits, thanks to [this article](https://medium.com/@lennyboyatzis/custom-pull-to-refresh-animations-in-react-native-1efac58609d3#.gfn32n6gz) for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using `react-native-pull-to-refresh-custom` lib

First create custom loader  `ListRefreshLoader`

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import colors from '../../assets/colors';
import {wp} from '../../styles/responsiveScreen';
import Circuler from './Circuler';

const ListRefreshLoader = ({refreshing}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      {refreshing ? (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Circuler color={colors.gray} size={wp(6)} />
        </View>
      ) : null}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: wp(15),
    height: wp(15),
    alignSelf: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default ListRefreshLoader;
```

Then use following way

```
import PullToRefresh from 'react-native-pull-to-refresh-custom';
import ListRefreshLoader from '../../components/Loader/ListRefreshLoader';

 <PullToRefresh
        HeaderComponent={() => <ListRefreshLoader refreshing={refreshing} />}
        headerHeight={60}
        refreshTriggerHeight={60}
        refreshingHoldHeight={60}
        refreshing={refreshing}
        onRefresh={onRefresh}
        style={styles.list}>
        <FlatList
          data={friendsList}
          viewabilityConfig={{
            itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 90,
          }}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={100}
          removeClippedSubviews
          style={styles.list}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          persistentScrollbar
          renderItem={renderItem}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={() => {
            return <View style={styles.listSeperator} />;
          }}
          ListEmptyComponent={totalUserFriends === 0 ? renderEmpty() : null}
          ListHeaderComponent={
            totalUserFriends !== 0 || searchText !== '' ? (
              <ListSearch
                placeHolder={`${t('Search')}...`}
                searchText={searchText}
                style={styles.searchStyle}
                fontName={'roboto-regular'}
                onSearchChange={(text) => setSearchText(text)}
                onClearSearch={() => {
                  setSearchText('');
                }}
                onEndEditing={() => setSearchText(searchText)}
              />
            ) : null
          }
        />
      </PullToRefresh>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written custom RefreshControl by merging below 2 methods

1. viewablityConfig of flatlist/sectionList will help in identifying the top element of the data.

   ```
   if (viewableItems[0]?.item?.url === firstCategoryUrl) {
       updateIsFocusOnTopOfScreen(true);
   } else {
       updateIsFocusOnTopOfScreen(false);
   }
   ```
2. After Identifying user is on top of the screen use panResponder to the flatlist/sectionList -> this is to identify the user is pulling the screen to bottom based on the this.pan.y._value increasing call your custom onRefresh method

   ```
   const mover = Animated.event([null, { dx: this.pan.x, dy: this.pan.y }]);
   onPanResponderMove: (e, gestureState) => {
       mover(e, gestureState);
       this.customRefreshControl(this.pan.y._value);
   },
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, create a custom ScrollView component and utilize the PanResponder API to handle touch events and scrolling.

```js
const CustomPullToRefresh = ({ refreshing, onRefresh, children }) => {
  const [isRefreshing, setIsRefreshing] = useState(false);
  const scrollY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: (event, gestureState) => {
        if (gestureState.dy > 0 && !isRefreshing) {
          scrollY.setValue(gestureState.dy);
        }
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: (event, gestureState) => {
        if (gestureState.dy > 100 && !isRefreshing) {
          setIsRefreshing(true);
          onRefresh();
        } else {
          Animated.timing(scrollY, {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: 250,
            useNativeDriver: false,
          }).start();
        }
      },
    })
  ).current;

  const translateY = scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 100],
    outputRange: [0, 100],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });

  const renderCustomRefreshIndicator = () => {
    if (isRefreshing) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.customRefreshIndicator}>
          {/* Your custom pull-to-refresh animation or UI elements here */}
          <Text style={styles.customRefreshText}>Refreshing...</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
    return null;
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ translateY }] }} {...panResponder.panHandlers}>
        {renderCustomRefreshIndicator()}
        {children}
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

And wrap your content in it.

```js
 <CustomPullToRefresh refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh}>
      {/* Your content goes here */}
      <Text style={styles.item}>Item 1</Text>
      <Text style={styles.item}>Item 2</Text>
      {/* Add more items here */}
 </CustomPullToRefresh>
```