# RefreshControl alignment

Tags: react-native

The standard `RefreshControl` is vertically centered when you pull to refresh:

[image]

Is it possible to have it stick to the top of the view instead (like the Facebook app)? I have tried setting the style, but nothing seems to make any difference.

Edit: Here is some of the styling props I have tried, none of them makes any difference

```
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          style={{alignItems: 'flex-start', justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignSelf: 'flex-start'}}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
        />
      }
```

I also tried `position: 'absolute'` and `top: 0` but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: can you show a bit of code which you tried?

Comment: I edited my question with styling examples

Comment: I think this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/41411089/7604342 can help you in getting your answer

Comment: As far as I can see that solution is to hide the original RefreshControl and build your own. I don't want to do that, since the original provides better UX. I just want to be able to position it.