# How to set Refresh Indicator of FlatList in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to set the refresh indicator of flat list in react native but don't know how to do it. List View has this prop :

```
refreshControl={<RefreshControl
                        colors={["#9Bd35A", "#689F38"]}
                        refreshing={this.props.refreshing}
                        onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
                    />
                }
```

But Flat List has only these :

```
refreshing={this.props.loading}
onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
```

Comment: Solution on this link works, Pls check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256972/how-to-customize-look-feel-of-react-native-listviews-refreshcontrol).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I found the solution! It might be the dummy but FlatList also has a prop called refreshControl like ListView but I just didn't test it! Just like this:

```
 <FlatList
    refreshControl={<RefreshControl
                    colors={["#9Bd35A", "#689F38"]}
                    refreshing={this.props.refreshing}
                    onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)} />}
 />
```

Comment: I believe FlatList is built from a ScrollView or a ListView because all of them are built around this VirtualizedList thing. I see them as wrappers with different APIs and for different purposes. The common aspect is they handle large lists. I think the solution posted for this above answer is correct. Additionally I think it is the Occam's Razer answer. RefreshControl is pretty much just a hook into that event (pull gesture when scrollY = 0), so if it gets called, you're good.

Comment: add tintColor as a prop for ios. Otherwise its work perfectly

Comment: I have tested this on react native 0.70.6 android app but this didn't working at all, It works perfectly only with scrollview.

Answer (score 5):

```
refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            isRefreshing={isRefreshing}
            onRefresh={loadProducts}
            colors={[Colors.GreenLight]} // for android
            tintColor={Colors.GreenLight} // for ios
          />
        }
```

this covers both ios and android

Answer (score 3):

In official doc for **RefreshControl** component it is stated as - **This component is used inside a ScrollView or ListView to add pull to refresh functionality. When the ScrollView is at scrollY: 0, swiping down triggers an onRefresh event**

So for **FlatList** don't use it directly because they provides the two special props named as **refreshing and onRefresh** - on which the standard RefreshControl will be added for "Pull to Refresh" functionality. Make sure to also set the refreshing prop.

**USAGE -**

Step 1:

```
const wait = (timeout) => { // Defined the timeout function for testing purpose
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeout));
}

const [isRefreshing, setIsRefreshing] = useState(false);

const onRefresh = useCallback(() => {
        setIsRefreshing(true);
        wait(2000).then(() => setIsRefreshing(false));
}, []);
```

Step 2:

Now use component as

```
<FlatList
     style={styles.flatListStyle}
     data={inProgressProjects.current}
     keyExtractor={item => item._id}
     renderItem={renderItem}
     showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
     refreshing={isRefreshing} // Added pull to refesh state
     onRefresh={onRefresh} // Added pull to refresh control
/>
```

For more information refer here -

https://reactnative.dev/docs/refreshcontrol

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onrefresh

Hope this will help you or somebody else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was passing `bounces={false}` to my Flatlist which was causing problem. This will not allow you to refresh. Remove it if you want to use the above one solution mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the `renderScrollComponent` to your FlatList component with the same `RefreshControl` component you have showed above. I have created a expo snack for this: https://snack.expo.io/rJ7a6BCvW

The FlatList is using VirtualizedList within itself, and for VirtualizedList component, it takes a `renderScrollComponent`: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/virtualizedlist.html#renderscrollcomponent

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work ! Object is not a function (evaluating 'this.props.renderScrollComponent(this.props)')

Comment: I also tried this. I am not sure if it is correct either because it seems it changes the whole scrolling component. Not just the refresh control. I will research more in future, please do update if you make any discoveries or are very sure about the `renderScrollComponent` method.