# How to replace react-native FlatlList indicator

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

[image]

I have write custom header in FlatList.
Now I want to replace the indicator with other picture both in Android and ios.
I have try many way to modify it, but all Failed.
[image]
here is my demo code https://github.com/kk412027247/react-native-custom-flatlist

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45676103/1393746

Comment: possible duplicate?