# React Native FlatList Loading Indicator not showing on light mode (iOS 13)

Tags: react-native, ios13, react-native-flatlist, ios-darkmode, activity-indicator

I noticed that when my phone is set to light mode, the loading indicator is so faint that it seems like its missing, but when switched to dark mode its clearly visible. In my specific case I am using a FlatList and have a refresh method that enables the pull to refresh functionality. I want to change the color of the loading indicator to a set color (lets say black in this case) and ignore the global theme color.

[Working (Dark Mode)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcM2s.png)

[Not Working (Light Mode)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZsdi.png)

Thank you!

Comment: I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659610/how-to-set-refresh-indicator-of-flatlist-in-react-native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of letting the OS choose the color based on dark/light mode, React Native's `ActivityIndicator` has a [color](https://reactnative.dev/docs/activityindicator#color) prop that you should check out. Maybe something like:

```
<ActivityIndicator color="#666" />
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. I am not using <ActivityIndicator> though. The activity indicator in the screenshot is part of the <FlatList> component, which why I am failing to change the color of it, thanks!

Comment: Gotcha. Looks like you can pass in a `refreshControl` prop: https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#refreshcontrol . Do that, and pass in an ActivityIndicator component.

Comment: ...or maybe you have to use an instance of the `RefreshControl` component? Sorry, less familiar with that. This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659610/how-to-set-refresh-indicator-of-flatlist-in-react-native

Comment: RefreshControl was the answer!

Comment: Nice! Please accept this answer if it was helpful. Thanks!