# Suspense in a FlatList

Tags: react-native, relayjs, relay, react-relay

I am developing a React Native app with Relay. I was using a `FlatList` inside a `ScrollView` like this:

```
<ScrollView>
  ...

  <Suspense>
    <FlatList />
  </Suspense>
</ScrollView>
```

I experienced issues with `ondEndReached` (it’s being called every time) so I moved to something like this:

```
<FlatList
  ListHeaderComponent={...}
  ...
/>
```

That works properly (`onEndReached` is called when it has to), but as I am using Relay I have to use the `Suspense` to add a Spinner/Loader and if I wrap the `FlatList` in the `Suspense` it will suspense all the component (including the Header) and not only the items.

Do you have any idea about how to advance? One alternative is to make it work the `FlatList` inside the `ScrollView` and the other one, to make it work the `Suspense` only for the items from the `FlatList`. Thanks!

Comment: can you not use the `refreshing` prop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Refresh Indicator of FlatList in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659610/how-to-set-refresh-indicator-of-flatlist-in-react-native)

Comment: As I am using Relay I don’t have any isLoading because it works with the Concurrent Mode from React, so I have to wrap it in a Suspense component.

Answer (score 0):

When using relay (or any other library with suspense and flatlist), you can replicate your list header in the suspense fallback, assuming it will suspend only in the initial render - onEndReach shouldn't trigger suspense.

```
const MyListHeader = () => <>{...}</>

const MyList = (props) => <FlatList {...props} />

const Fallback = () => (
  <MyList
     ListHeaderComponent={MyListHeader}
     data={[]}
     renderItem={() => null}
     scrollEnabled={false}
  />
)

const MyListWithRelay = (queryRef) => {
  const queryKey = usePreloadedQuery(MyQuery, queryRef)
  const { data } = usePaginationFragment(graphql`...`, queryKey)
  return (
    <MyList
      {...}
      data={data.connection.edges}
    />
  )
}

const Screen = (queryRef) =>  (
  <Suspense fallback={<Fallback />}>
    <MyListWithRelay queryRef={queryRef} />
  </Suspense>
)
```