# How do I change the RefreshControl's loading indicator?

Tags: react-native

I have a `FlatList` that uses a standard `RefreshControl`, like so:

```
<FlatList 
    data={items}
    refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={loading} onRefresh={this.refresh} />}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (<ListItem item={item} />)}
/>
```

This renders the native refresh indicator when doing a pull-to-refresh action.  My questions are as follows:

1. Can I change the icon/image that the `RefreshControl` uses to a custom one that matches my app's design better?
2. Is there a way to just create a replacement `RefreshControl` that works on both Android and iOS?

I found [this example](https://medium.com/@lennyboyatzis/custom-pull-to-refresh-animations-in-react-native-1efac58609d3) of a customized pull-to-refresh, which is what a of other questions/answers here reference, but that solution does not work on Android (at least not per my testing).

Comment: I think you are using props wrong, can you try `refreshControl={() => <RefreshControl ..../>}`

Comment: No, that is not how the `refreshControl` property works.  You have to pass in an element, not a function.  The code I've included in my question works perfect, I just want to change the refreshing indicator image.

Comment: Uhm I see. Sorry for misguiding

Comment: Hey, any luck with that?

Comment: @nikasv nope, I couldn't figure it out so I moved on.  I would still love to know if this is possible.

Comment: Was searching for it whole day as well(. Will comment if something comes up

Comment: @user2719094 Having the same problem. Have to found the solution?

Comment: I think that it is current not possible , only on android you have a property that may help to change the color of the indicator:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol#colors

Comment: I'm using this library [react-native-pull-refresh](https://github.com/NadiKuts/react-native-pull-refresh) for custom refresh animations. Only does not work on IOS yet, so I'm thinking of contributing.

Comment: One workaround that I found is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256972/how-to-customize-look-feel-of-react-native-listviews-refreshcontrol

Answer (score -2):

You Can Use The colors Props of `RefreshControl` you can pass an array containing a group of color's

for example `colors={["gray","orange"]}`

this will change the color of the indicator each time it completes one rotation

```
import {
  FlatList
  RefreshControl
} from "react-native"

<FlatList 
    data={items}
    refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl 
         refreshing={loading} 
         onRefresh={this.refresh}
         colors={["gray","orange"]} 
        />
    }
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (<ListItem item={item} />)}
/>
```